# Custom folder/inbox views in an Outlook Web Add-in

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm looking for a way to display a custom view of the inbox - one that isn't necessarily constrained to a simple tabular grid.  Basically a calendar view of all past emails (weekly and monthly).

I would also like to make it work as a Web Add-In so I can use it in the Office 365 Web Outlook, along with my Windows Desktop Outlook 2016 app (and Android would be a bonus).

Two main questions:

1. Is there a way to customize the current folder view for emails using a Web Add-In to support something like this - a calendar layout for all my past emails?
2. Alternatively, is there a way to link to a custom View using a Web Add-In that is NOT in the context of a selected message?

   I've read about module extensions and being able to add an entry point from the navigation pane, but unfortunately those are limited to Office 2016-only in Windows.

   From what I can tell the Ribbon support for a web add-in, runs in the context of a message, too (is that correct?) so what (if any) other options are there for running at a more high level, global context, not initiated by viewing a message?

I've proofed out a custom view using the office API via Office.js (still lots of work left, but the only remaining unknown for this route is #2).  Unfortunately I'm loading that view by clicking on any email then clicking the button from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your questions. The add-in API doesn't support to custom layout for folder view. The add-in runs on single message and cannot run at "higher" level now. If you need such features, please add your request here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins.

Thanks again for your feedback,
Outlook Engineering Team

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've seen limited (or very old) mentions of anything definitive regarding activating an add-in outside a message, so this settles it and I can now give up on my project for a while instead of wasting more time.  It's a bit reminiscent of the Windows 8 / 8.1 RT / Phone Store apps.  The scenario I've experienced time and time again: I have an idea, spend a few days researching the feasibility of it, can't do it, give up.  Every Win (and now Office) Store App idea I've had ended the same way.  :) thanks.